# Swiftui Error: Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm setting up Firebase with Email authentication, I copying a source code from a website, on which they use the following code, but they do not mention anything about this error.

I have tried every question on SO and GitHub but none of them seem to work.

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        TextField($email, placeholder: Text("email address"))
        SecureField($password, placeholder: Text("Password"))
        if (error) {
            Text("An error")
        }
        Button(action: signIn) {
            Text("Signing in")

        }
    }
}
```

That line in the middle of the if statement is giving me the following error:

Text("An error")

```
Type of expression is ambiguous without more context
```

Comment: And where does `error` come from?

Comment: I meant the variable and why can’t you sanitize your error messages before posting them here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like this is an old SwiftUI code. Placeholder argument of the `TextField` changed a bit since then.

change it to:

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        TextField("email address", text: $email)
        SecureField("Password", text: $password)
        if (error) {
            Text("Oh an error!")
        }
        Button(action: signIn) {
            Text("Signing in")
        }
    }
}
```